# Phone not keeping emails

Tags: iphone, email, mobile-mail

My iPhone has recently started deleting my email automatically from my Phone after a couple of weeks. I am wondering how exactly I can keep all emails that come to my phone as I need them.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information like what phone do you have, what version of the OS, what app you are using, what service, etc.  Remember, we are not there to look over your shoulder, so the more ***relevant*** info you provide, the better.

Answer (score 1):

If the account is associated with Outlook or similar, it has a feature called "mail days to sync". To increase to show all emails, open settings, go to Mail, tap on the offending account, then change mail days to sync from the default amount to the longest period of time. This will restore all previous emails that have gone missing, and keep any new ones.